# Sending Outlook E-mail using Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I'm interested in using Powershell to send e-mail through Outlook using a single line of code. The closest thing I've found is this command for Gmail:

```
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port 587 -from 'myself@gmail.com' -to 'myself@gmail.com' -subject 'Test' -body 'Body' –UseSsl
```

But I want to do something similar with Outlook. Is there a way to take the short script below and turn it into a single line of code? Thanks!

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "name@domain.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Subject of E-Mail"
$Mail.Body ="Text of Body"
$Mail.Send()
```

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to read [`about_Functions`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx)

Comment: How to convert a script into a single line of code (no `#comments` in script allowed): 1) Place cursor at beginning of code. 2) Press the End key 3) Press the Semicolon key 4) Press the Delete key 5) Repeat until code is one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application;$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0);$Mail.To = "name@domain.com";$Mail.Subject = "Subject of E-Mail";$Mail.Body ="Text of Body";$Mail.Send()
```